# Create a REST proxy for SOAP service in wso2 esb

Tags: rest, soap, wso2, esb

We have a SOAP service that I want to proxy in WSO2 ESB. This is for POC that I am working on. I came across various documents and some explanation on forums but nothing concrete yet. I looked at API option but couldn't get anything to work. Whats the best way to do this? Can the transformation occur in esb itself or is the api the only option? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can better choose RESTAPI option.
Here is the [documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/REST+Support) for that

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by couldn't get this working? This is not a big configuration, you need to define your proxy service such that you send the message (REST message) to the back end as a SOAP message. Here is a sample configuration.

```
   <proxy name="StockQuoteProxy" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true">
      <target>
         <endpoint>
            <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"
                     format="soap11"/>
         </endpoint>
         <outSequence>
            <send/>
         </outSequence>
      </target>
   </proxy>
```

You can call this proxy in REST manner and it will automatically send the message to the backend SOAP service.

you can do it with the sample axis2 client as below.

```
ant stockquote -Daddurl=http://localhost:8280/services/StockQuoteProxy -Drest=true
```